# Adding an event listener using an object’s property

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to have is a working button and input form for my code which is a block                        in an object literal. My form shows fine when I run the code, but doesn’t output a value. Why not?

```
<input class="number" type="number" placeholder="Enter some number...">
<button>enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>

<script>
var input = document.querySelector("#number");
var output = document.querySelector("#output");

var button = document.querySelector("button");
add.button.addEventListener("click", add.number, false);
button.style.cursor = "pointer";

var add = {
    number: function () {
        amount = parseInt(input.value);
        if (amount == 5) {
            output.innerHTML = alert("true");
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = alert("false");
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#number")` aka `document.getElementById('number')`.

Comment: Neither `add` nor `add.button` exist at the moment you are trying to access it. Maybe you just mean `button`. Learn how your browser's developer tools work so that you will be able to debug problems like this on your own.

Comment: `output.innerHTML = alert("true");` doesn’t really make any sense. `output.innerHTML = "true";`, maybe?

Comment: If it wasn't clear to you where to first look for this error, then you MUST learn to look at the error or debug console in the browser to see where your script errors are.  This would have been a script error and would have given you an error message and a line number for the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the function before you can pass it to addEventListener otherwise you are just passing undefined.

```
<input class="number" type="number" placeholder="Enter some number..." id="number">
<button id="button">enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>

var input = document.getElementById("number");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var add = {
    number: function () {
        amount = parseInt(input.value, 10);
        if (amount === "5") {
            alert("true");
            output.innerHTML = true;
        } else {
            alert("false");
            output.innerHTML = false;
        }
    }
};

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", add.number, false);
button.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/zw7e7q72/

Comment: I can actually use this answer . what im going to do is calculate math with the input forms from a user input rather than just say a prompt . It's for design purposes . Thanks !